# How to get rid of css inherited from a css file?

Tags: css

I have original.css file that i can't remove or change from the page.
original.css

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

The radio buttons are showing a border and only way it seems to go away its when using chromedev tool I remove `border-collapse:collapse` from the original.css. I been trying to do overwrite it using the code below but nothing works. Any suggestion on how to remove border?

[image]

```
<style>
input[type="radio"] {
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 1px;
   border: none;
   border-spacing: 0;
   CellSpacing:-1;
}
</style>
<div class="contact-input-item" style="padding-left: 8.9cm; ">
     <label><b>By:</b> 

    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="send_by" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rbl" BorderStyle="None" Style="display: none">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Email" Value="Email" />  <asp:ListItem Text="fax" Value="fax" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList></label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More specific CSS will override less specific css.  So if you can use the class name as well as the type of item inside of your style tags that might be able to push out that "Table" specification.

```
<style> .contact-input-item input {...etc...} </style>
```

Then as a last resort you can use `!important`:

```
<style> 
  .contact-input-item input {
           border-collapse:separate !important;
  } 
</style>
```

Comment: Also be careful mixing-and-matching.  You have an external style doc, an internal style definition, and inline styles.  Pick one of these, preferably external style docs.

Comment: Thank you Julian.  I was typing quickly and didn't spend the extra moment to get that formatting right.